# Структура объектов Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игра, в которой есть разный муссор. 
Они обладают полями типа:
- тип (как индикатор, который указывает на то какие параметры будут дальше)
- скорость (зависит от типа)
- урон (зависит от типа)
- скин (зависит от типа)

Я создал префаб з скриптом который подбирает необходимый скин и задает все параметры, но думаю как красиво и понятно все организовать?
Возможно списком enum создать типы, а в скрипте класса определять поле с конкретным типом и методом что задают параметры в зависимости от типа? 
Но что тогда делать с колайдерами? Их тоже динамично подставлять? Где хранить информацию о всех типах и характеристиках?

Или проще сделать разные префабы с разными характеристиками но одним скриптом?
Подскажите, как правильно подобрать структуру к такому классу объектов? :)

Comment: И еще важная информация. Если вы ставите минус вопросу, то будьте добры обяснить хотя бы в коментариях. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен, ответ получился неконкретный и размыт. Но я придумал решение и обясню какое:
Для начала я создал два enum списка в генераторе объектов:  (и да, я не использую здесь оригинальный код ;)

```
public enum OTypes {
    easy, //1
    normal, //2
    hard, //3
    ultraHard, //5
    danger //1
}

public enum FieldsToOTypes {
    score = 0,
    speed = 1,
    damageToLocation = 2,
    damageToPlayer = 3
}
```

Также в классе создал словарь:

```
Dictionary<OTypes, int[]> OTypesDictonary = new Dictionary<OTypes, int[]> {
        // rules to build difrent types of O
        { OTypes.easy, new int[] {1, 1, 1, 0} }, // meaning of array indexes can see in FieldsToOTypes
        { OTypes.normal, new int[] {1, 2, 2, 0} }, // score, speed, damageToLocation, damageToPlayer
        { OTypes.hard, new int[] {2, 3, 3, 0} },
        { OTypes.ultraHard, new int[] {3, 5, 5, 0} },
        { OTypes.danger, new int[] {0, 5, 0, 1} }
    };
```

Что это такое? Думаю, такой код позволит легко добавлять новые виды объектов, также создание и задание параметров будет похоже на фабрику и имеет понятный вид:

```
OEntity.score = OTypesDictonary[type][(int)FieldsToOTypes.score];
        OEntity.speed = OTypesDictonary[type][(int)FieldsToOTypes.speed];
        OEntity.damageToLocation = OTypesDictonary[type][(int)FieldsToOTypes.damageToLocation];
        OEntity.damageToPlayer = OTypesDictonary[type][(int)FieldsToOTypes.damageToPlayer];
```

Вседа рад советам и критике моего решения :)

Comment: Я тут узнал о json и понял что лучше переделать все в отдельный файл но структура останеться :)

Comment: Логика фабрики осталась, но изменились некоторые данные. Теперь использую Json для учета объектов и специальные классы для Сериализации данных, а дальше так же обрабатываю параметры.
        var dataAsJson = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
        Objects = JsonUtility.FromJson<Locations>(dataAsJson.text);

Answer (score 1):

100% imho

Кому как проще, я как **программист** больше полагаюсь на скрипты, чем на настройки через инспектор, потому что больше доверяю контролю версий исходников через **git** со всеми вытекающими.

Однако, если в проекте есть **не программисты**, им это не удобно, им удобно какраз как в юнити заведено, т.е. префабы, инспектор и т.д.

В проектах, которые я делаю один, я по минимому стараюсь использовать **программирование мышкой** как мы это называем, т.к. искать что то в сцене не люблю. мне проще в ide нажать **ctrl+f**

А как должны быть устроены обьекты - художнику (Вам) виднее, будь то enum или любая другая особенность c#/ооп , это сильно контекстно зависимо.

Comment: Интересный ответ, согласен было бы отлично меньше мышкой возить. Правда когда в команде только я и художник, решать приходиться мне вот и спрашиваю за более практическую реализацию.  :)